How to click id by Puppeteer, but id is changed each access?
I want to click check-box inperson name by using Puppeteer.
And the person name has unique id which is diffrent each time.

I have tried to make this method

const selector = '#id^="/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+-[0-9]+/g"';
await page.click(selector) 

But Puppeteer says error which is:
    DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#id^="/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+-[0-9]+/g"' is not a valid selector.

I thought my reguler expression is wrong so I made sure its correct.
const id = '9538-0';
const regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+-[0-9]+/g;
const found = id.match(regex);
console.log(found); // [ '9538-0' ]


Here is HTML at check box.


       <span _ngcontent-ng-c184323="" class="recipient-item-desktop">MIKE CHASE (12345086)</span>
       <span _ngcontent-ng-c184323="" class="recipient-item-desktop">AGO</span>
       <span _ngcontent-ng-c184323="" class="recipient-item-desktop">$0.00</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>


And this is  snapshot


my software versions
Lang : JavaScript
node.js : v20.16.0 (node -v)
Puppeteer : puppeteer@23.0.2  (npm list --depth=0)


Could you please teach me why I am not able to click check box by ID(id="9538-0") or
How to do it best.
Thank you for your time.

Is 8532876 an ID that remains the same?

From where did you get the idea that you could use regular expressions in this context? If you can link whatever documentation or resource you’re looking at that you are seeing as indicating such a facility, we might be able to help clear up the root of your confusion.

The ID you're regexing isn't in the markup you show.

Puppeteer uses CSS selectors, which do not support regex.
You can try something like this, and it should work:
const selector = '#9538-0';

If the name always appears first in the DOM, you could also use a positional CSS selector.

I assume OP used a regex because the id changes, so presumably hardcoding it like this won't help them much. Then again, it's not really clear what OP's use case is.

Yes, that's why I recommend using a positional selector, where you can target the first element no matter what ID it's using.

Positional selectors can be failure prone as well. If the order changes you click the wrong element.

Everything can be a failure when you know nothing about the context, however, the position is always much less likely to change than the name or the ID.
That's the thing about scraping, your solution must adapt to what the DOM offers you.

When the position changes, it's a silent failure--you pull the wrong data. When the id changes, you get an explicit error and you know it's time to fix the scraper. Positions aren't necessarily less likely to change than classes or IDs. Anything can change at any point, but yeah, context matters. We don't know if OP is scraping or testing, but in testing, positions are considered unambiguously worse than IDs and classes, although even IDs and classes are considered poor practice compared to user-visible selectors (which Puppeteer doesn't offer, so getting sort of off topic).

It doesn't have to be a silent error if you do the proper checks when fetching the data. Again, position can be the best or worst idea depending on the context, as can ID or any other approach.
Given the context we have (that mailbox screenshot), do you have a better CSS selector than using the first column?

I'd have to see more context to provide the best approach, but "grab the first checkbox on the page" is an extremely weak condition, very unlikely to be the best. Also, your answer is an ID, which isn't present in OP's structure. So the question/answer/thread doesn't make much sense. I got here trying to find a duplicate to another question, but this thread isn't a suitable resource for "dynamic id" as the title indicates.

This is my solution by using very nice lib, names 'puppeteer-select'.
Its very helpful if you want to click containing specific text.
//npm install puppeteer-select
const select = require ('puppeteer-select');  

let name ='span:contains(' + 'MIKE CHASE (12345086)' +')';

const elm= await select(page).getElement(name);
await elm.click();


Please edit your question for clarity and NOT add multiple answers that do not appear to be answers.
